# how can I put two bar charts to one graph?

Tags: r

I use two variables from a dataset:
I got the graph for one of them:

```
barchart(data_derm$PP_SD_ARBVLZ=="1")
```

I want to put the graph for this variable data_derm$PP_SD_ARBTLZ=="1"  next to the other graph to one graph

thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` ??

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, this question will be difficult to answer definitively.  One possibility is to use something like [?layout](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/layout.html):

```
layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1))
barchart(data_derm$PP_SD_ARBVLZ=="1")
barchart(data_derm$PP_SD_ARBTLZ=="1")
```

See the [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html) website for more.

Answer (score 0):

So you want two `graphs` in one `figure` if I am understanding you correctly. 
If you want the commands from the base package. You can use:

```
> data(mtcars)
# par(mfrow=c(row, col))  and "row" is the number of plots you put in a row and same for "col"
> par(mfrow=c(1,2))
> barplot(mtcars$mpg)
> boxplot(mtcars$mpg ~ as.factor(mtcars$cyl))
```

You can use other functions if you don't mind using with GGPLOT2.. etc.
[image]